# Why does MVC look for the file in a location that isn't linked to?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

This doesn't make sense to me, why does it look for the index within an equipment folder?!?!?

I get this warning message in the windows application event logs usually at least once a day.

```
Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
Exception message: The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Equipment/Index.aspx
~/Views/Equipment/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Equipment/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Equipment/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

I have the following structure:

Controllers (folder)

- Service.cs (file)

View (folder)

- Services (folder)

  - Equipment.cshtml

There are only links to the equipment URL are:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Equipment", "equipment", "services", null, new { @class = "dropdown-item" })

and

@Html.ActionLink("Equipment", "equipment", "services", null, new { @class = "green" })
```

In case it is relevant this is the view code for Equipment within the Services.cs file:

```
[Route("equipment")]
public ActionResult Equipment()
{
    return View();
}
```

P.S. Using MVC 5.2.9, Razor 3.2.9 and .Net Framework 4.7.2

EDIT: As requested by Victor here is the RegisterRoutes method, there is nothing special occuring.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Error", // Route name
        "Error", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Error", action = "Index" });
}
```

For Yiyi You, here is the code for ServicesController.cs:

```
[RoutePrefix("services")]
public class ServicesController : Controller
{
    [Route]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("equipment")]
    public ActionResult Equipment()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: **1)** Check your sources:  do you have references to the `Index` view in your code at all? Especially check, does the `Index` method declared in the **`Services`** controller?  **2)** Add code of the `public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` to the post, please. Might be helpful. **3)** In you code above the `equipment` is action method name. But from some reason this name is become the controller name - according to the exception message. **This is means that you didn't include all parts of code related to the problem.**

Comment: @Victor 1)  Equipment > Index is definitely not referenced in code 2) I've included RegisterRoutes in the edit. 3) yes, this is very puzzling, I've included the only two links to the equipment page which are both using the services controller.

Answer (score 0):

For the error,you can try to change the folder name and cshtml file name:

```
View (folder)

  Equipment (folder)

    Index.cshtml
```

Or you can try to share more code in Service.cs.

Comment: The problem I have is that I cannot seem to reproduce the error myself, although the logs do show it... Please see the EDIT where I've included the code for Services.cs... it's nothing special.